# SQL query select data between two date fields

Tags: sql, select, date, datefield

I am trying to select data from a table, using two date fields (startdate and enddate). With both date fields in the where clause no results are returned, with the startdate field taken out results are returned, what is going on? Can anyone help with this dilemna

My code is:

```
   SELECT WPP.USERID, 
          WPI.EMAIL, 
          WPI.FIRSTNAME, 
          WPI.LASTNAME, 
          WPI.INSTITUTION 
     FROM WEBPROGRAMPARTICIPANTS WPP 
     JOIN WEBPERSONALINFO WPI ON WPP.USERID = WPI.USERID 
     JOIN WEBPROGRAMS WP ON WPP.PROGRAMCODE = WP.PROGRAMCODE 
    WHERE CONFIRMED = 1 
      AND WP.PROGRAMTYPE IN ('1') 
      AND WP.PROGRAMSTARTDATE >= '2009-01-02' 
      AND WP.PROGRAMENDDATE < '2009-09-15'
 GROUP BY WPP.USERID, 
          WPI.EMAIL, 
          WPI.FIRSTNAME, 
          WPI.LASTNAME, 
          WPI.INSTITUTION 
   HAVING COUNT(WPP.PROGRAMCODE) > 1 
 ORDER BY WPP.USERID,
          WPI.EMAIL
```

EDIT:

here is a result set to look at

```
USERID PROGRAMSTARTDATE        PROGRAMENDDATE
------ ----------------------- -----------------------
26167  2009-03-09 00:00:00.000 2009-06-12 00:00:00.000 
26362  2009-03-09 00:00:00.000 2009-06-12 00:00:00.000 
26411  2009-03-09 00:00:00.000 2009-06-12 00:00:00.000 
26491  2009-03-09 00:00:00.000 2009-06-12 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Post the rows that are returned when one date is taken out (only a few rows and only the columns userid, programstartdate, programenddate are needed).

Comment: Is it possible that none of the confirmed, program type 1 programs begin on or after January 2, 2009?

Comment: adding to Eric J.'s suggestion, when selecting the rows, order by WP.PROGRAMSTARTDATE desc

Comment: Are you sure there are results that have a startdate greater than 2009-01-02 and an enddate less than 2009-09-15?

Comment: There definitely are programs that start after that startdate, our programs only run for a couple of months at a time.

Comment: @mattgcon, i dont doubt that there are programs, but are there userids that have more than 1 in that time period?

Comment: here is a result set to look at
26167 2009-03-09 00:00:00.000 2009-06-12 00:00:00.000
26362 2009-03-09 00:00:00.000 2009-06-12 00:00:00.000
26411 2009-03-09 00:00:00.000 2009-06-12 00:00:00.000
26491 2009-03-09 00:00:00.000 2009-06-12 00:00:00.000

Comment: @mattgcon: you're going to hate me...but could you please add PROGRAMCODE to the result set.   =)

Comment: mattgcon, i added your data to the question and formatted it.  please take a look to see if it formatted correctly.  if so, can you tell us what it is from?  i dont see any reference to userid,email,names etc.  can you give col headers or something like that?

Comment: @akf, I imagine the column headers are userid, programstartdate, programenddate, which is what Eric J. initially asked for.

Comment: David that is correct
AKF the headers are USERID, PROGRAMSTARTDATE, PROGRAMENDDATE

Comment: that makes sense (read: i should have noticed that) - i have updated my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have no records in your DB with

`CONFIRMED = 1 AND WP.PROGRAMTYPE IN ('1') WP.PROGRAMSTARTDATE >= '2009-01-02'` ??

EDIT: As [@David Andres](https://stackoverflow.com/users/162355/david-andres) pointed out The "`COUNT(WPP.PROGRAMCODE) > 1`" clause looks like a candidate for the culprit.

Comment: @Mitch: Feel free to include that if you like in your answer.

Comment: The having clause is pretty simple, yet very much needed. What I need to accomplish is to return a result set of users that have participated in more than one program, over a course of some date range.

Comment: @mattgcon: at this point it's just a potential cause of your woes.  Bear in mind you're limiting the result set to only those that are confirmed and are in program type 1, and then further limited this set to those users who participated in several programs.  Try taking the HAVING clause out first and see if the results match better to your expectations.  You may also want to modify your count to COUNT(DISTINCT WPP.PROGRAMCODE) just to ensure a user hasn't enrolled within the same program more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to be honest, it looks fine to me.  I suspect the having statement filtering your results, or a combo of the where and having statement.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your answer is zero, as in "zero users participated in more than one program during that date range"

What you can do to confirm this is modify your query slightly to show how many programs each user *did* participate in:

```
   SELECT WPP.USERID, 
          WPI.EMAIL, 
          WPI.FIRSTNAME, 
          WPI.LASTNAME, 
          WPI.INSTITUTION,
          COUNT(WPP.PROGRAMCODE)
     FROM WEBPROGRAMPARTICIPANTS WPP 
     JOIN WEBPERSONALINFO WPI ON WPP.USERID = WPI.USERID 
     JOIN WEBPROGRAMS WP ON WPP.PROGRAMCODE = WP.PROGRAMCODE 
    WHERE CONFIRMED = 1 
      AND WP.PROGRAMTYPE IN ('1') 
      AND WP.PROGRAMSTARTDATE >= '2009-01-02' 
      AND WP.PROGRAMENDDATE < '2009-09-15'
 GROUP BY WPP.USERID, 
          WPI.EMAIL, 
          WPI.FIRSTNAME, 
          WPI.LASTNAME, 
          WPI.INSTITUTION 
 ORDER BY COUNT(WPP.PROGRAMCODE) DESC, 
          WPP.USERID,
          WPI.EMAIL
```

This should list for you every user and the count of projects for that date range, ordered first by the count, then by the criteria you originally set up.  It removes the having clause, which *seems* to be the cause of your pain.

Answer (score 0):

Gentlemen, thank you very much for all your help. Through analysis of all what you have said and trying the different suggestions out, I have actually found out that the code is right. However, during that time frame, users did not attend more than one program during that time frame. If I go back just one more year the expected data comes up. So basically it was just a simple matter of logical attendence factoring of the user to the programs.

Thank you all again.